# How do I view the mime-type of an email attachment in Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I received an email with attachments and I'm interested in the mime-type of those attachments. How do I look at it in Outlook 2016?

Comment: Maybe you can check the Content-type from the message header:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/attached-files-and-messages